# MooTools: How do package data for a POST ajax request?

Tags: ajax, post, mootools

I'm using MooTools 1.4.1.  I want to create an ajax post requst, but I can't figure out how to construct the "data" attribute, which I wish to contain the name value pairs of a form whose id is "myForm".

```
        $('save').addEvent('click', function(event) {
            var req = new Request({
                method: 'post',
                url: 'save',
                data: { ... },
                onRequest: function() { 
                        // on request
                },
                    onComplete: function(response) {
                        alert(response);
                    });
        });
```

Anyone know how I should populate the "data" attribute?  Thanks, - Dave

Comment: Just send an object - value pairs  `data:{foo:"bar"};`

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$('myForm').toQueryString();
```

Alternatively, The MooTools More package has a `Form.Request()` class to send a Form using Ajax.

Comment: You can put the result of "$('myForm').toQueryString()" after the "data:" block?  That's currently not working for me, but maybe there's something else going on with my program.

Answer (score 1):

As Savageman commented, you can throw your form element into `toQueryString()` and send it through in the data property, or by running `.send()` or `.post()` on the request object.

You also seem to be missing a closing squiggly bracket.

Anyhow, this is how I make AJAX requests:

```
new Request({
    url: 'http://url/to/ajax/script.php',
    onSuccess: function(data) {
        doStuff();
    }
}).post('action=foo&bar=baz');
```

I'd recommend you use Request.JSON if you're planning on sending stuff back. It's less "shotgun approach"-ey.

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass form element to "data" property, and conversion is automatic.

```
var req = new Request({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'example.com/form.php',
    data: $('myForm'),
    onRequest: function() { 
        // on request
    },
    onComplete: function(response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

**data** - (mixed: defaults to '') The default data for Request:send, used when no data is given. Can be an ***Element***, ***Object*** or ***String***.
*If an **Object*** is passed the ***Object:toQueryString*** method will be used to convert the object to a string.
*If an **Element*** is passed the ***Element:toQueryString*** method will be used to convert the Element to a string.

http://mootools.net/docs/core/Request/Request